# How can I access http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm using localhost for my WordPress (xampp). I've changed the wp-config.php but when I want to access (http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/install.php) this shows up:

Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\install.php on line 36

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress/wp-load.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-admin\install.php on line 36

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you, there is no file install.php found.

To install wordpress, you just need to enter the url:

http://localhost/wordpress

which is the root folder of your wordpress site. In this folder there is the wp-config.php, if you need to set your database information manually, this is the place.